# Get class and object attributes of class without methods and builtins

Tags: python, introspection

Say I have this class:

```
class MyClass(object):
  my_attrib = 'foo'
  my_other_attrib = 'bar'

  def mymethod():
    pass
```

Now how can I get ONLY the attributes of the class MyClass, WITHOUT methods and builtins like `__dict__` and so on?

I want to get a dictionary like `{'my_attrib':'foo', 'my_other_attrib':'bar'}`, when applied to the class above.

Comment: Why can we not use `__dict__` ?

Comment: Why is `__init__()` setting class attributes?

Comment: @Jakob: I only want to get all the non-method attributes, but __dict__ gives me everything. how do I distinguesh the values of __dict__ between method and attributes?

Comment: @Sven: I did not think about that when writing the example. Changed the example.

Comment: Why would you like to do this?  There's probably an easier way to achieve whatever you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can filter out everything you don't need from `__dict__`:

```
def getAttributes(clazz):
    return {name: attr for name, attr in clazz.__dict__.items()
            if not name.startswith("__") 
            and not callable(attr)
            and not type(attr) is staticmethod}
```

**Edit**: An alternative that behaves slightly differently for class properties and descriptors:

```
def getAttributes2(clazz):
    attrs = {}
    for name in vars(clazz):
        if name.startswith("__"):
            continue
        attr = getattr(clazz, name)
        if callable(attr):
            continue
        attrs[name] = attr
    return attrs
```

(In practice, this should be rarely different from the first version.)

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I want. Just one addition: I added `and if not type(attr) is staticmethod`, to also filter out static methods (for general purpose).

Comment: @2rs2ts There is a difference between `clazz.some_static_method` and `class.__dict__['some_static_method']`.  The former invokes the descriptor get method and indeed returns a callable.  The latter retrieves the raw `staticmethod` object, which is not callable.  I'll update the answer with a cleaner alternative.

Answer (score 4):

This should get you close:

```
import inspect

class MyClass(object):
  my_attrib = 'foo'
  my_other_attrib = 'bar'

  def mymethod():
    pass

for name, value in inspect.getmembers(MyClass):
    if not inspect.ismethod(value) and not name.startswith('__'):
        print name
```

This outputs:

```
my_attrib
my_other_attrib
```

---

NOTE - There may be a better / more-official way to do this, but this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

`__dict__` gives you all that but you could use a `C` extension maybe to get what you want. Not sure why you would do that though.

You can use `types` ([doc](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html)) to distinguish between members of `__dict__`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin `dir()` to get everything, then filter. You will not need the `inspect` module.

```
def get_attrs_without_methods(klass):
    attrs = dir(klass)
    d = {}
    for x in attrs:
        if x.startswith('__'): continue
        value = getattr(self,x)
        if not callable(value):
            d[x] = value
    
    return d
```

Sometimes, you may want to get **ONLY** class variables instead of class variables **AND** instance variable.
You can filter out instance variables by relying on `__dict__`. Or you can get the attributes using `__class__` and filter out the methods. `__class__` does not return instance variables.

```
#after collecting your attributes using the above example...
for attr, value in vars(obj).items():
    d.pop(attr) #remove instance variables from the dict

#both vars(obj).items() and obj.__dict__.items() return similar iterable.
```

Note that if the object implementation overrides `__dict__` and returns None, `vars(obj)` and `obj.__dict__.items()` will not return a dictionary.